# How to apply search interface to the list of wrapper class?What should we write in search function

Tags: visualforce

Want to search   below the name from below list dynamicalyy;

Here is the controller

```
public with sharing class Sim_EventOfficeContactsController {

    public List<OfficeContactWrapper> officeContacts {get;set;}
    private List<Office_Contact__c> toBeDeleted{get;set;}
    public Integer selectedIndex{get;set;}
    private Integer index{get;set;}

    private String eventId;
    public id eventAccountid;

    public String searchstr{get;set;}

    public Sim_EventOfficeContactsController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        toBeDeleted = new List<Office_Contact__c>();
        eventId = controller.getId();
        List<Event_and_Lecture__c> eventList = [select id,account__r.Id from Event_and_Lecture__c where id = :eventId limit 1];
        eventAccountid = eventList[0].account__r.Id;
        system.debug('eventAccountid: '+eventAccountid);
        initOfficeContacts();    
    }


    public pagereference dosearch(){
        String strg = '%'+searchstr+'%';
        =[SELECT id,name FROM Office_Contact__c WHERE name like:strg];
       return null;
    }    



    public boolean getHasContacts(){
        return officeContacts.size()>0;
    }

    //methods for getting list of contacts
    public void initOfficeContacts()
    {   
        officeContacts = new List<OfficeContactWrapper>();
        index = 1;
        //if viewing on standard controller (account), add in filter for accountId
        for(Office_Contact__c officeContact : [SELECT id, name,Event_and_Lecture__c,email__c,CORE_Referral_Manager__c ,Phone__c, account__c, Type__c, Preferences__c
                                               FROM Office_Contact__c WHERE account__c = :eventAccountid ORDER BY Name asc LIMIT 1000]){
              OfficeContactWrapper ocw = new OfficeContactWrapper(officeContact,index);
            officeContacts.add(ocw);
            index++;                
        }

    }

    //save all records that were updated
    public void save() 
    {
        List<Office_Contact__c> toUpsert = new List<Office_Contact__c>();
        for(OfficeContactWrapper ocw: officeContacts){
            toUpsert.add(ocw.officeContact);
        }
        upsert toUpsert;
        delete toBeDeleted;
        initOfficeContacts();
    }

    public void add()
    {
        Office_Contact__c ref = new Office_Contact__c(Event_and_Lecture__c = eventId, account__c = eventAccountid);
        officeContacts.add(new OfficeContactWrapper(ref,index));
        index++;
    }

    public void delRow()
    {   
        integer index = 0;
        System.debug('rowIndex for delete'+ selectedIndex);
        for(OfficeContactWrapper ocw: officeContacts){
            if(ocw.rowIndex == selectedIndex){
                if(ocw.officeContact.Id != null)
                    toBeDeleted.add(ocw.officeContact);
                break;
            }
            index++;
        }
        officeContacts.remove(index);
        save(); 
    }
    class OfficeContactWrapper{
        public Office_Contact__c officeContact{get;set;}
        public Integer rowIndex{get;set;}
        public OfficeContactWrapper(Office_Contact__c officeContact,Integer rowIndex){

            this.officeContact = officeContact;
            this.rowIndex = rowIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace the `officeContacts` you could do this:

```
public pagereference dosearch() {

    // Modify class properties
    officeContacts = new List<OfficeContactWrapper>();
    index = 0;

    String strg = '%'+searchstr+'%';
    for (Office_Contact__c : [
            SELECT id, name
            FROM Office_Contact__c
            WHERE name like :strg
            AND account__c = :eventAccountid
            ORDER BY name
            LIMIT 1000
            ]) {
        officeContacts.add(new OfficeContactWrapper(c, index));
        index++;
    }
    return null;
}
```

and then refactor to remove duplicated code (as this query is present elsewhere).

Comment: as i want to search from the list of wrapper.Want to show all list of wrapper and then do the search

Comment: @SarthakGarg The logic looks like it already lists the full set to start with; then if you have a button that invokes `dosearch`, clicking that button will cut down the rows to match the search string.

Comment: by the way how to search from list of wrapper in visualforce page???Do i need to implement this using jquery datatables????